# mysqldumpで一括保存する際、データベース単位でファイル保存する方法はあるでしょうか？

Tags: mysql

**--all-databasesのように1ファイル保存ではなく、データベース単位で保存したいのですが**
・個別指定するのは大変なので、まとめて指定する方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

このWebページが参考になるのではないでしょうか。
http://easyramble.com/backup-mysql-and-restore.html

```
#!/bin/bash

# バックアップ先ディレクトリ
BACKDIR=/var/backup/mysql

# バックアップ用の MySQL ユーザーとパスワード
DBUSER=mysql_backup
DBPASS=password

# バックアップ先ディレクトリ再作成
rm  -rf $BACKDIR
mkdir -p $BACKDIR

# データベース名取得
DBLIST=`ls -p /var/lib/mysql | grep / | tr -d /`

# データベースごとにバックアップ、バックアップファイルは日時を付ける
for dbname in $DBLIST
do
  [ $dbname = "performance_schema" ] && continue
  table_count=`mysql -u $DBUSER -p$DBPASS -B -e "show tables" $dbname | wc -l`
   [ $table_count -ne 0 ] && mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASS $dbname > $BACKDIR'/'$dbname'_'`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S`'.sql'
done
```